# messagecreate dont working with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i don't know why but my code dont work without any error:

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [ 'DIRECT_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MESSAGES' ] });

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("ready");
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content.endsWith("quoi")) {
        message.channel.send("feur");
    };

    console.log("message");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using discord.js v13 creating a [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client) with [intents](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Intents) should be formatted like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
  ],
});
```

The intents format is `Discord.Intents.FLAGS.<insert the intent here>`.  You can find a full list [Intent FLAGS](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).

This is included in the [Updating to v13 from v12 discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#intents)